# Add a property to an element with D3 .datum()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Can I add a single property to an existing set of props using `.datum()`?
So that it didn't overwrite everything with this new property but added it.

I suppose it can be something like `element.datum({'prop':1})` but this one just replaces the whole dataset with this single property.

Answer (score 2):

You may just get a reference to the data bound and act on it any way you like:

```js
var b = d3.select("body");

// Create and bind data
b.datum({ "a": 123 });
console.log(b.datum());  // Object {a: 123}

// Retrieve and manipulate data
var obj = b.datum();     // Get a reference to the data bound
obj.a = 456;             // Modify
obj.b = "extension";     // Extend
console.log(b.datum());  // Object {a: 456, b: "extension"}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```